# How to search one string after another, line by line in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I a file with content as bellow

```
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
string_A_to_be_searched
blah blah blah
string_B_to_be_searched
string_B_to_be_searched
blah blah blah
string_A_to_be_searched
```

I would like to search for string_A_to_be_searched, return the line number,

Then, only after finding string_A_to_be_searched, I can search for string_B_to_be_searched. I keep searching for string_B_to_be_searched until string_A_to_be_searched is hit again.

I would like to use PYTHON. Since Python only implements for loop with item in a range, specified by a set, and my set, which is enumerate(file) is alway indexed from 0 to end, the search will keep searching from line zero instead of the line where the first instance of file is found.

what I have tried is something like this. I have block of code within a class whose lineNumber, lineFound are its variables to be used.

```
file = open('fileName.txt')
lines = file.readline()

for lineNumber, line in enumerate(Lines):
    if string_A_to_be_searched in line: 
          self.lineNumber = lineNumber
          for lineNumber, line in enumerate(Lines):
                if string_B_to_be_searched in line: 
                      self.lineNumber = lineNumber
                      self.lineFound.append(lineNumber)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. In oder to help you, could you add your expected output and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have added some codes to explain what I tried before. Basically it is 2 for loops. I hope to start searching in the second for loop from the lineNumber where the phrase is found. However, it doesn't work like that. For loop just reset to loop variable to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take your sample and create a script that not only solves your problem, but eliminates the second loop. Hope this helps!

```
lines = []
with open("sample.txt") as filen:
  lines = filen.readlines()

string_A_found = False
for lineno, line in enumerate(lines):
  search_string = "string_A_to_be_searched" if not string_A_found else "string_B_to_be_searched"
  if search_string in line:
    print(f"{search_string} found at {lineno}")
    string_A_found = True if search_string == "string_A_to_be_searched" else False
  if string_A_found and "string_A_to_be_searched" in line:
    print(f"String A found again at {lineno}")
```

The output of which is:

```
string_A_to_be_searched found at 2
string_B_to_be_searched found at 4
string_A_to_be_searched found at 7
```

Comment: pretty nice thinking. You basically apply a logic "and" for this situation and prevent looping search. Thank you so much.